# Java - sort only subsection of array

Tags: java, sorting

I have an array of characters

```
String a = "badabcde";
char[] chArr = a.toCharArray(); // 'b','a','d','a','b','c','d','e'
```

What's the easiest way to sort only a section of the array, given a start and end index?

```
// 'b','a','d','a','b','c','d','e'
subSort(array, startIndex, endIndex);

Ex: 
subSort(chArr, 2, 5);
// 'b','a','a','b','c','d','d','e' // sorts indices 2 to 5
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think [public static void sort(char[] a,
                        int fromIndex,
                        int toIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(char[],%20int,%20int)) answers your question.

```
String a = "badabcde";
char[] chArr = a.toCharArray(); // 'b','a','d','a','b','c','d','e'

// fromIndex - the index of the first element (inclusive) to be sorted
// toIndex - the index of the last element (exclusive) to be sorted
Arrays.sort(chArr,2,6);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [public static void sort(char[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) in `Arrays` class.

In your example:

```
Arrays.sort(chArr,2,6); // note that fromIndex is inclusive
                        // but toIndex is exclusive
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Arrays.sort([], int startIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-char:A-int-int-).

```
 String a = "badabcde";
 char[] chArr = a.toCharArray(); // 'b','a','d','a','b','c','d','e'
 Arrays.sort(chArr, 2, 5);
 System.out.println(new String(chArr)); // this prints baabdcde
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Example usage:

```
Arrays.sort(chhArr, 2, 5);
```